# How can I link the indicator of a carousel to a target collapse accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap carousel at the top of the page and a collapse accordion at the bottom working independently, both with the same number of items.

I want to be able to click on the slide indicator(or anywhere on the slide, i.e. caption, button) and have the target accordion panel show content.

Here's snippet of my code:

```
 <!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-sevenhabits" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-sevenhabits" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-sevenhabits" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-sevenhabits" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-sevenhabits" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-sevenhabits" data-slide-to="5"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-sevenhabits" data-slide-to="6"></li>
</ol>
```

...

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Habit #1: Be Proactive
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Be Proactive is about taking responsibility for your life. You can't keep blaming everything on your parents or grandparents. Proactive people recognize that they are "response-able." They don't blame genetics, circumstances, conditions, or conditioning for their behavior. They know they choose their behavior.<br><br>
    Reactive people, on the other hand, are often affected by their physical environment. They find external sources to blame for their behavior. If the weather is good, they feel good. If it isn't, it affects their attitude and performance, and they blame the weather. All of these external forces act as stimuli that we respond to.<br><br>
    Between the stimulus and the response is your greatest power—you have the freedom to choose your response. One of the most important things you choose is what you say. Your language is a good indicator of how you see yourself.<br><br>
    A proactive person uses proactive language—I can, I will, I prefer, etc. A reactive person uses reactive language—I can't, I have to, if only. Reactive people believe they are not responsible for what they say and do—they have no choice.
  </div>
</div>
```